# PHP script passing whole object from class to class

Tags: php, postgresql

To describe my problem well i will firstly write few words about how my script work so far.
 So there is a server which from time to time update `XML` under some address (lets say its (`https://someaddress.com/feedback.xml`). Then i have created a script which is being run one time daily ( using `cron`) that read the `XML` given and put new object in my database.
Now i want to get those objects in my another script ( it is important for me to create independent `.php` file which loads only newest object from `feedback.xml`. And here is the problem. I could load those values directly from `database` but this way I have a whole list of all records (I want only newest one) solution to this could be adding column in table which stores `boolean` value to `New?` question, but I cannot change in any way my `database`. I believe i could load those object to some `array` but then how can it be passed to another script? bellow i post method which i use to store records to `database`

```
$xmlstr = file_get_contents(url);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

foreach ($xml->value as $a) {

    //method to check if record exist

    $rec= new Item($db);

    //method to set values of obj

    $rec->Store();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your scripts run on the same server, then there are a number of different approaches that might work:-

(1) If your database already has a timestamp or a unique ID for the relevant row then you may be able to query the DB, order by one of these columns and then limit the results to 1 record.

```
select [fields] from records order by created desc limit 1
```

(2) As well as writing the results to the database, you could also persist them in a local file and read from that each time (how big are these result sets?).

(3) Another option could be to use Memcached to persist the result set in memory so that your scripts remain decoupled but access to the information is very fast. If you haven't used Memcached before then do take a look - it's very good for just this sort of task and is simple to use.

If your scripts are running on different severs then (1) would work but the others would need  further thought.

Comment: (3) Another option could be to use Memcached to persist the result set in memory so that your scripts remain decoupled but access to the information is very fast. - This option sound really interesting for me. I will check for some documentation of `Memcached` or some examples and i will report how it works. Thank You Purpletoucan!

Comment: After reading `php manual` i find that `Memchached` is not part of php and require installation which is impossible for me because i am not server administrator. about (2) how big are these result sets? each time i update database records i got about 20 new records, but i dont knew this value - it is variable so i ges `desc` is also not good for that..

Comment: It's a bit messy to persist some of the information outside of the DB, but with restrictions on your hosting environment, that may be inevitable. Perhaps your cron job could write just the number of records into a file and your script retrieves the records limiting based on that number, or you go fully for option (2). It's all a bit 'icky' but in a restrictive environment, other options evaporate. It doesn't sound as if the size of the result set will impact option (2).